# Passing Parameters through URL Protocol

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have this url protocol configured:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\IDAD]
@="URL:IDAD Protocol"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\IDAD\DefaultIcon]
@="idad.exe,1"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\IDAD\shell]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\IDAD\shell\open]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\IDAD\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\idad\\idad.bat\" \"%1\""
```

And my `idad.bat` is something like this:

```
@echo off
echo password | "C:\Program Files (x86)\AnyDesk\AnyDesk.exe" %1 --with-password
```

I want to create my own anydesk executer to use locally on a website, it doesn't do what I want it to do.

At the moment if do idad:99999999 it runs the anydesk but without the 99999999 part.

Is something wrong? If so in which part?

I was expecting it to open with the Id I put.